# Form not include in email body

Tags: javascript, html, smtp

I use smtpjs to send form to my email, but when i click submit its just only email, body is empty, form not include with that.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sendEmail() {
            Email.send({
                Host: "smtp.gmail.com",
                Username : "test@test.com",
                Password : "test@test.com",
                To : '<test@test.com>',
                From : "<test@test.com>",
                Subject : "INSTRUMEN SELF ASSESSMENT RISIKO COVID-19",
                Body : "<email body>",
            })
            .then(function(message){
                alert("mail sent successfully")
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="testbox">
      <form method="post">
        <h1>INSTRUMEN SELF ASSESSMENT RISIKO COVID-19
</h1>
        <div>
          <h4>How often do you meet in person with teachers at your child's school?</h4>
          <div class="question-answer">
            <label><input type="radio" value="none" name="meet" />Almost never</label>
            <label><input type="radio" value="none" name="meet" />Once or twice per year</label>
            <label><input type="radio" value="none" name="meet" />Every few months</label>
            <label><input type="radio" value="none" name="meet" />Monthly</label>
            <label><input type="radio" value="none" name="meet" />Weekly or more</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div> <input type="button" value="Send Email" onclick="sendEmail()"/> </div>
      </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you setting the email body? Or is it just `<email body>`?

Answer (score 0):

You're aren't including any values to be sent to the function, also you can't detect any of inputs as they don't have any id, so I would suggest this solution

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sendEmail() {
            let body = "";
            if(document.getElementById('never').checked)
               body += document.getElementById('never').value;

            // same thing for the other radio inputs...

            Email.send({
                Host: "smtp.gmail.com",
                Username : "test@test.com",
                Password : "test@test.com",
                To : '<test@test.com>',
                From : "<test@test.com>",
                Subject : "INSTRUMEN SELF ASSESSMENT RISIKO COVID-19",
                Body : body,
            })
            .then(function(message){
                alert("mail sent successfully")
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="testbox">
      <form method="post">
        <h1>INSTRUMEN SELF ASSESSMENT RISIKO COVID-19
</h1>
        <div>
          <h4>How often do you meet in person with teachers at your child's school?</h4>
          <div class="question-answer">
            <label><input type="radio" id='never' value="Almost 
             never" name="meet" />Almost 
             never</label>
            <label><input type="radio" id='onceOrTwice' value="Once or 
            twice per year" name="meet" />Once or 
            twice per year</label>
            <label><input type="radio" id='evFewMonths' value="Every 
            few months" name="meet" />Every 
            few months</label>
            <label><input type="radio" id='Monthly' value="Monthly" name="meet" 
             />Monthly</label>
            <label><input type="radio" id='weekly' value="Weekly or 
             more" name="meet" />Weekly or 
             more</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div> <input type="button" value="Send Email" onclick="sendEmail()"/> </div>
      </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helped you

Comment: Hi alikondie, thanks for your answer. I was try your code but still cant get output from form, any suggest ?

Comment: I Mean, how to make question and answer include in body ? Your code just include answer sir